# Active property on sub-menu in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, submenu

I have been struggling with this problem for weeks now and would really love to find a solution to this CSS-issue. If it's even possible, how do I make the sub-menu stay visible when the parent is active?

The CSS works great with the :hover property, but cant figure out how to make the sub-menu block stay visible with :active.

```
<nav id="menu" role="navigation">  
    <?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
</nav><!-- #menu -->
```

```
#menu ul li:hover ul.sub-menu,
#menu ul li:hover ul.sub-menu li,
#menu ul li:hover ul.sub-menu li a { display: block; }
```

Would really appreciate some help or any ideas at all so I don't waste more time on trying to solve this if it can't be solved with CSS only.

Regards, Bellisia

Edit:

```
<nav id="menu" role="navigation">  
    <div class="menu-headmenu-container">
        <ul id="menu-headmenu" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-17">
                <a href="http://yyy.com/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15">
                <a href="http://yyy.com/services/">Services</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20">
                        <a href="http://yyy.com/contact/">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav><!-- #menu -->
```

Comment: @StephenHarris This is what we have _close_ votes (off topic) or _flag_ (move to SO) for.

Comment: I thought it was since it works on other projects I've worked with, so I figured it must have to do with WordPress and that something is blocking the active property. Then again, I'm new to WordPress.

Comment: Btw, thank you for pointing me in right direction and my question is now put on StackOverflow instead! :)

Comment: @Kaiser - I know, I flagged it, but I thought I would make Bellisia aware of it.

Comment: I am aware of it now, but still, thought it was WordPress related, I wouldn't ask it here if I thought otherwise.

Comment: @Bellisia Please don't add another answer on SO. Mods will move yours over there - in this case you have a dublicated Q on SO then...

Comment: How does the HTML for the navigation look like, i.e once its generated by Wordpress and sent to the browser?

Comment: Don't sweat it. I'll migrate this one to SO for now, and if necessary the moderators there can merge your two questions.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on say Contact (sub nav item), 
the (*current_page_item*) class should be applied to that li?

in which case, could you not just use..

```
#menu ul li ul.sub-menu li.current_page_item { display: block; }
```

which would indicate that its in use and displayed as block on that page load?

Comment: I tried, but that doesn't activate it. Since I'm already using :hover it disappears again.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to play with the positioning for the submenu, but here is a fiddle that shows how to do it with just CSS alone.  When you hover over Link 2 you will see a child `<ul>` appear with three links.

http://jsfiddle.net/ryancowles/63XBy/

Answer (score 0):

The "Child Combinator" selector is what you are looking for, try the below CSS.

`.current_page_item > ul { display: block; }`

The only caveat is that "Child combinator" selector will select children only one level deep, so it will not work for nested sub-menu's.

HTH

P.S: I am presuming here that you've setup Wordpress to apply the "current_page_item" class to the parent menu item that was clicked.

Comment: I tried that too, but it doesn't work. And I'm guessing it's because of the hover effect I'm using. I just need it to stay there it something is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

After endless hours I realized that I didn't use the > correctly and here's how it ended up looking like:

```
#menu ul.menu > li.current_page_item > ul.sub-menu { display: block; }
```

Works like a charm! But that's only for the parents, I cant get the sub-menu items to stay visible when clicked, any ideas?